# reinterpret_cast conversion chain correctness

Tags: c++, types, casting, type-conversion, reinterpret-cast

According to the [type aliasing rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast), i assume that:

1) direct conversion of `uint64_t*` to `uint32_t*` - is **incorrect** (i can't access the data through the result ptr. and be sure i will get the correct value)

2) conversion chains is **OK** (i can safely access the data)

```
uint64_t* -> unsigned char* -> uint32_t*

uint64_t* -> void* -> uint32_t*
```

Am i understanding the rules correctly or not?

I'm always prefer to use **union**s instead, to prevent any possible ptr. conversion problems (which can cause data corruption), but it is not always possible (and good) solution.

Comment: No, reinterpreting a char pointer as a pointer to a type that isn't the actual type is UB, so your chain doesn't work.

Comment: Also using a union for achieve the same result(s) is UB.

Comment: That's weird that cppreference's [Type aliasing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing) section only talks about polymorphic objects.

Comment: If at all possible, you should probably try to truncate the pointed-to value instead of playing around with the pointer itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2) conversion chains is OK (i can safely access the data)
>
> ```
> uint64_t* -> unsigned char* -> uint32_t*
>
> uint64_t* -> void* -> uint32_t*
> ```
>
> Am i understanding the rules correctly or not?

No. A chained `reinterpret_cast` like that will not be any more correct than a direct `reinterpret_cast`.

> I'm always prefer to use unions instead

Type punning with a union also violates aliasing rules.

---

If you have a pointer to `uint64_t`, and you want to use four of the eight bytes (I'm assuming a 8 bit byte) contained in the object and interpret them as a `uint32_t`, then you must first decide on which of the eight bytes you want to use. After all, all eight of them won't fit in a single `uint32_t`. Do you want the low order bytes, or the high order bytes? Or perhaps something more exotic, like every other byte? Also consider, in which order should the bytes be in the resulting `uint32_t`.

If you want particular bytes based on their significance, then the portable way is to use bit shifts and masks.

If you want particular bytes based on their position in memory, then the portable way is to use `std::memcpy`.

Comment: "**the portable way to read the correct bytes is to use bit shifts and masks**" - as i see it, _0xFF_ mask will bring me the _Least Significant Byte_, which lies st the _lowest_ addr. in the _little-endian_ machine, while opposite in the _big-endian_, so the same mask will target diff. bytes of memory. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Alternative would be to `memcopy` bytes you want into receiving variable.

Comment: @AmaboCarab correct. Masking gives you the low order byte, regardless of endianness.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot `memcpy` doesn't violate aliasing rules, but it it does read bytes of different significance depending on endianness. But that might just be what a reader is looking for, so I added it to the answer.

Comment: @AmaboCarab For portability, you'll probably want to use conditional compilation to define constants you can use for masking, based on the target platform's endian-ness.  For example, you could use an `#ifdef` block to set `constexpr uint64_t LEAST_SIGNIFICANT_BYTE_UINT64` to `0x00000000000000FF` on big-endian systems, or `0xFF00000000000000` on little-endian ones.  (Apologies if I mixed those two up, I get my endian-ness backwards sometimes.)

Comment: @Justin Time, LSB mask will be ALWAYS 0xFF no matter which endiannes is used. You masks still correct through, BUT for the other purpose: to access '_HIGHEST_ADDR_BYTE_' :)

Comment: @AmaboCarab Oh, my bad.  Thanks for pointing that out, I find endian-ness kinda confusing sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

If you're sure your machine is either big or little endian (which is almost always the case), you might use htonl() to detect endianness. On both architectures, an uint64_t can be viewed as uint32_t[2], it's just the byte order that's different. Therefore, you might reinterpret_cast and add the offset based on endianness. While this is non-standard, there's just one possible implementation of big endian and of little endian (pigeonhole principle). Note that this won't work on e.g. middle-endian architectures (which are rare but exist), or any architecture where endianness cannot be defined.

Comment: Middle endian architectures are not *imaginary*, but perhaps rare enough these days to be ignored.

Comment: yep, sorry for claiming them imaginary.